# How to reestablish double in c++

Tags: c++, string, double, type-conversion, representation

When representing `double` number its precision corrupts in some degree. For example number 37.3 can be represented as 37.29999999999991.

I need reestablishing of corrupted `double` number (My project requires that). One approach is converting `double` into `CString`.

```
double d = 37.3;
CString str;
str.Format("%.10f", d);

Output: str = 37.3;
```

By this way I could reestablish corrupted `d`. However, I found a counterexample. If I set

```
d = 37.3500;
```

then its `double` representation sometimes be equal to 37.349998474121094. When converting `d` to `CString` output is still 37.3499984741, which is not equal to 37.3500 actually.

Why converting 37.3500 didn't give desired answer, while 37.3 gave? Is there any ways to reestablish double?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try `snprintf` with `%g`.

Comment: it is not "corrupted", it is the floating point representation. You can't un-corrupt floating point precision. If you need decimal accuracy, then you need a dedicated decimal type.

Comment: no no, @ chris, snprintf with %g rounds up to 4 decimal places. I need 10 decimal places at least..

Comment: So what would you do about *exactly* 37.29999999999991? If you round it to 37.3 (using `sprintf` or whatever method) it will also get "corrupted"...

Answer (score 4):

> Why converting 37.3500 didn't give desired answer, while 37.3 gave?

By accident. The representation of `37.3` happened to be close enough that rounding to 10 decimal places gave the expected result, while `37.3499984741` didn't.

> Is there any ways to reestablish double?

No, once information has been lost, you can't recover it. If you need an exact representation of decimal numbers, then you'll need a different format than binary floating point. There's no suitable decimal type in the C++ language or standard library; depending on your needs, you might consider libraries such as [Boost.Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html) or [GMP](https://gmplib.org/). Alternatively, if you can limit the number of decimal places you need, you might be able to multiply all your numbers by that scale and work with exact integers.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done to some extend, but not easily.  Since the string representation is base 10, but the internal representation in base 2, there is rounding involved when converting one into the other.  So when you convert the decimal "37.35" to double, the result is not identical to the original number.  When converting that number back to a string, the computer cannot know for sure what number was there in the first place, because there are several decimal numbers that result in the same double.  However, you can add the constraint that you want the shortest possible decimal string that results in the given double, then there is a very good chance that it recovers your original string precisely.  An algorithm using that constraint has been developed by David Gay. [Here's the source code](http://www.netlib.org/fp/), you need both g_fmt.c and dtoa.c, and [here is a paper about it](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/doc/90/4-10.ps.gz).  This is the default algorithm used [in Python since Version 3.1](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.1.html).